# Two jQuery scripts conflicting on one page

Tags: jquery

I am no coder so no idea how i can combine the below two scripts so that they both work. I have attempted numerous thing but to no avail. Any help is appreciated.

1.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/scripts/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" media="screen" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('.fancybox').fancybox({
                  padding : [25, 15, 20, 30],
                    helpers: {
                    title  : null,
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
```

2.

```
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.answer').hide();
        $('.question').live('click', function() {
            $(this).next().slideToggle();
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: why are you including two BTW?

Comment: Yeah, what? You have jquery-latest and jquery 1.4.2 included.

Comment: remove one of the jQuery's

Comment: I remove one and that script doesn't work.

Comment: only load jQuery once, before all plugins and other dependent code. `live()` is deprecated so will have to convert to `on()` or not use latest version

Comment: Ok thanks. I had a third jquery above those that i didnt even realise was there. So have removed both of the ones noted and now it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, I would also separate your links (top of page) and your scripts (bottom of page).

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/scripts/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" media="screen" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.answer').hide();
            $('.question').on('click', function() {
                $(this).next().slideToggle();
            });

            $('.fancybox').fancybox({
                padding : [25, 15, 20, 30],
                helpers: {
                    title  : null,
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: `$.live()` is deprecated as of jQuery 1.7

Comment: `$('.question').on(event, func)` isn't equal to `$('.question').live(event, func)` as live also works for `.question` elements added later.

Answer (score 0):

Only load the more recent version of jQuery (maybe not `latest`--that's a bit risky), and then convert your script to this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.answer').hide();
    $('.question').on('click', function() {     // <--- 'live' becomes 'on'
        $(this).next().slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: Amazingly fast help. Respect.

Answer (score 0):

Remove jQuery 1.4.2 include and change the second script to this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.answer').hide();
    $(document).on('click', '.question', function() {   //$.on() version of $.live()
        $(this).next().slideToggle();
    });
});
```